# get post content into header

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have to get the post content into the tag `<head>`.
I was trying with this code into the header.php file of my theme:

```
if(is_single()){
$stringa = the_content();
}
```

but it doesn't work.

how can i do?
thanks

Comment: edited the comment. <head> was not visible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The functions `the_content()` and `get_the_content()` are meant to be used inside the [WordPress loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), which means you can't just use them at will.  You'll need to build a loop inside your `header.php` file that queries the WordPress database, fetches some content, and uses it as necessary.

Basically, wrap your `the_content()` call inside:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    ...
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Then you'll be able to fetch post content anywhere on the page ... however, I don't quite understand why you're trying to get the post content inside the `<head>` section of the page.  `<head>` is used for style declarations, `<script>` tags, and meta information about the page ... *not* for actual page content.  If you're trying to get specific information about the current page, I'd recommend using a different function entirely.

Comment: Well ---- I don't know about the person who initially asked the question - but I need the post content if I am to successfully build a Twitter card.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
$stringa = get_the_content();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (is_single()) 
{
  the_post();
  $content = get_the_content();
  rewind_posts();
}
```

It's important to put rewind_posts(), otherwise post loop will not work in other templates.